# Unity how to get Transform.forward in float form

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to create mid-air movement for a 3D platformer, and I am trying to use transform.forward and transform.right as floats. However, I can't seem to figure out how to change them into float values, since they are Vector3 variables. Here is what I have tried:

```
velX = transform.forward * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
velZ = transform.right * Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
```

What I got was an error saying the `transform.forward` and `transform.right` are Vector3 values, wheras velX and velZ are floats.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve here. The .forward and .right field returns you a Vector3. The x, y and z field are all from type float and you already got the values in float form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
velX = (transform.forward.x + transform.right.x) * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
velZ = (transform.forward.z + transform.right.z) * Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
```

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve but if you're looking for a scalar representation of a vector, that is the actual vector length, then `Vector3.magnitude` will get it. It'll return the distance between the given vector origin and its endpoint.

You get the vector magnitude by calling:

```
Vector3.magnitude(point.forward)
```

And I'm almost certain you can even do:

```
point.forward.magnitude
```

You can go [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-magnitude.html) and [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/what-is-vector3-magnitude.50125/) for further reference.

Again, I'm not sure if that's what you're trying to get but I hope it helps.

Comment: and what are you going to use moveDirection for?